# What is the meaning of "free credit" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of *free credit* at [this website](http://www.english-test.net/toeic/listening/furniture_store_announces_special_sales_weekend_by_means_of_a_radio_commercial.html#TOEIC_Listening_Comprehension)?

Google translate says that *credit* means `the ability of a customer to obtain goods or services before payment, based on the trust that payment will be made in the future.`

How can credit be free?

Does *free credit* mean that the customer don't have to pay a certain amount of money in the future?

Comment: Credit is payment deferred. Money has a time value. $100 today is worth more than $100 a year from now, even in the impossible scenario where you could be absolutely assured that payment will be made. In other words: credit comes with interest. Unless the creditor waives that interest, as the advertisers in your example are doing. In other words: unless it's *free credit*.

Comment: As generally understood, the term "free credit" means that if a purchaser follows the "rules" laid out by the seller, the seller (or the agency the seller designates) will allow the purchaser to pay for the purchase in "installments" over a period of months, without having to pay any "interest" on the borrowed money.  In effect, the seller pays the interest on the money, as a discount on the purchase price.

Comment: @HotLicks. Can I say that *free credit* = *zero interest installment*?

Comment: Remembering of course the economist's favourite saying: _there is no free lunch_. So when you're offered (interest-)free credit you are not being charged interest, but don't think for a moment that the price itself does not have that credit risk baked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mentioned is short for **interest-free credit** — [Investorwords](http://www.investorwords.com/10070/interest_free_credit.html)

> *noun* a credit or loan where no interest is paid by the borrower
>   *"The company gives its staff interest-free loans"*

In your case, it appears the goods are sold on credit without interest. Also, the comments explain it well.